# What does differential equations with constant coefficient mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I read the definition of differential equations with constant coefficient.

I am very confuse.

What does it mean?
What are some example?

Comment: Can you tell us what definition you read? Where did you read it? Was there really no example after the definition?

Comment: A differential equations with constant coefficients means a differential equation in which the coefficients are constants. Which part of this do you need help with, Bob? By the way, congratulations on that Nobel Prize.

Comment: ax'' + bx'+cx = 0

Comment: so a, b, c are constant?

Comment: Yes, I am a genious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A linear second-order ODE is an equation of the form
$$
a(x)u''(x)+b(x)u'(x)+c(x)u = f(x),
$$
where $u \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ is the unknown defined on some interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $a$, $b$, $c$, and $f$ are given functions defined on $I$.

The equation has constant coefficients if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are *constant* functions throughout $I$ (but not $f$).